# What exactly is a method in Python?

Tags: python, oop

In the code below, the object `a` has two functions as attributes: one is a class attribute while one is its own instance attribute.

```
class A:
    def foo(*args):
        pass

a = A()

def bar(*args):
    pass

a.bar = bar

print(a.foo)
print(a.bar)
```

What I expected was that both `bar()` and `foo()` would be methods of the object `a`, but, from the output of this code, it turns out that this is not the case—only `foo` is a method of `a`.

```
<bound method A.foo of <__main__.A object at 0x0000016F5F579AF0>>
<function bar at 0x0000016F5F5845E0>
```

So what exactly is a method in Python? Is it a class attribute that holds a function definition, which seems to be the case.

And why isn't the attribute `bar` considered a method by Python? What exactly is the idea behind this behaviour of Python?

Comment: A function usually defined on the *class* that is then bound to an *instance* becomes a method.

Comment: Compare with `print(A.foo)` which gives: `<function A.foo at 0xhhhhhhhh>`

Comment: @khelwood What exactly do u mean by *usually*?

Comment: @coderboy I'm hedging my bets in case someone comes in and tells me I'm technically wrong.

Comment: @coderboy 1) `bar` is still a function and 2) bound methods behave differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A method is an instance of the class `method` returned by, among other things, the `__get__` method of a `function`-valued *class* attribute.

`a.bar` is an *instance* attribute, not a class attribute.

When looking for `a.foo`, Python first looks for `A.foo`. Having found it, it next checks if its value has a `__get__` method (which, as a `function` value, it does.) Because `A.foo` is a descriptor (i.e, has a `__get__` method), its `__get__` method is called: `a.foo` is the same as `A.foo.__get__(a, A)`. The return value is a `method` object, whose `__call__` method calls the underlying function with the object and its own arguments. That is,

```
a.foo(x) == A.foo.__get__(a, A)(x)
         == A.foo(a, x)
```

Because `a.bar` is an instance attribute, the descriptor protocol is *not* invoked, so `a.bar` is the exact same object as `bar`.

(This is an extremely condensed version of the contents of the [Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), in particular the [section on methods](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods). I highly recommended reading it.)

---

The lookup for `a.bar` proceeds by first looking for `bar` in `A.__dict__`. When it isn't found, Python looks in `a.__dict__`, and finds a `function` to call: end of story.

Comment: All functions have a __get__ method on them? Right? That __get__ method is what differentiates between methods and functions. I want to ask how does the ```__get__``` method of ```bar``` realise that the function is being called as an instance's attribute?

Comment: @coderboy that's how the [lookup chain](https://realpython.com/python-descriptors/#how-attributes-are-accessed-with-the-lookup-chain) works.

Comment: You have it backwards. `bar.__get__` is never called in the first place, *because* the function object is accessed via an instance of the object.  The chart in [this blog post](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/) is helpful.

Comment: After looking at the chart myself, I realized my description was not quite correct (there's some trickiness to distinguish between data and non-data descriptors). I think the description of `a.foo` is now correct, and I've added an analogous description of `a.bar`.

Comment: The trickiness being: a class attribute with a `__get__` method shadows an instance attribute with the same name, but the instance attribute shadows other class attributes. (The chart is [here](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/#object-attribute-lookup) inside the blog post.)

Comment: @chepner I think u were almost correct. In the call ```a.bar()```, Python realises that ```bar()``` isn't an attribute on ```A.__dict__```, and then checks ```a.__dict__``` for ```bar```. Since this ends with a match, the ```bar()``` function is called.

Comment: I think I got it :) Thanks @chepner for the link in the comment..

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are setting the attribute to an instance of the class, not itself.

Following your example, let's set:

```py
A.bar = bar
```

You'll see that the output is:

```py
print(A.bar)
# <function bar at 0x0000021821D57280>

c = A()
print(c.bar)
# <bound method bar of <__main__.A object at 0x0000021821EEA400>>
```

Bound methods are methods that require the actual instance of the class itself. This is why we typically have `self` as the first parameter: the instance knows to pass itself to the function when it gets called. By setting the function as an attribute to the instance, the method is not bound, and the first parameter will not be itself.

We can see this behavior if we set our function `bar` as the following:

```py
def bar(*args):
    print("Argument types:", *map(type, args))

a.bar = bar
a.bar()
# Argument types:

A.bar = bar
c = A()
c.bar()
# Argument types: <class '__main__.A'>
```

We see that with a bound method, it passes itself to the function. This is the difference between setting a method as an attribute versus actually setting it to the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

`a.bar` is not a BOUND method. It is a callable that has been set to an attribute. This means, among other things, that it doesn't automatically get the `self`.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.baz = 'baz'
        
    def foo(self):
        print(self.baz)
    
def bar(obj):
    print(obj.baz)

a = A()
a.bar = bar

a.foo()
# prints baz

a.bar()
# raises TypeError: bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'obj'

a.bar(a)
# prints baz
```

You can make a method into a bound method with `types.MethodType`:

```py
a.bar = types.MethodType(bar, a)
a.bar()
# prints baz
```

This only binds it to the instance; other instances won't have this attribute

```py
a2 = A()
a2.bar()
# AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'bar'
```